# How to host Multiple .Net-Core WebApi using OWIN Under the same URL and all API use the same Middleware pipeline

Tags: owin, asp.net-core-webapi, web-hosting, owin-middleware

I have a requirement where Multiple WebAPI services(i.e. WebAPI1,WebAPI2,WebAPI3 etc.) work for the same product and as per requirement we need to use single Middleware to Authenticate the request for All WebAPI services(i.e. WebAPI1,WebAPI2,WebAPI3 etc.)

after lots of R&d i found nothing that's works for Multiple API. Guys Please suggest the better way.

Comment: can you elaborate do all of the api have different routes such as /api/ , /api1/ etc do all the api reside in singe sln or are the different projects.

Comment: I have a single sln with multiple API Projects

Comment: so every api project must be having a different middileware chain , what you can do is combine api projects and distinguish them based on routes,this way you have a single middleware with multiple api paths